# Change dates dynamically to fetch data from google calendar api

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm currently fetching data from google calendar freebusy endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy with the following request object:

```
{
    "timeMin": "2021-12-31T10:30:00.000z",
    "timeMax": "2022-01-12T09:30:00.000z",
    "calendarExpansionMax": 11,
    "groupExpansionMax": 11,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "ali.mojiz1@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to change the dates dynamically in the aforementioned object so that I can get data from the last and next 30 days based on current date for e.g. timeMin changes to 22nd December'21 and timeMax changes 22nd Feb'22.

I've tried the following to get data for the next 30 days from today but it doesn't work:

```
{
    "timeMin": "2022-01-22T10:30:00.000z",
    "timeMax": "{date.add(30).format('yyyy-MM-ddT23:59:59Z')}",
    "calendarExpansionMax": 11,
    "groupExpansionMax": 11,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "ali.mojiz1@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What language are you using? Can you show a more complete code sample including the definition of the variable `date`? And specify what exactly happens when you say it "doesn't work". Do you get an erro? Wrong results? No results?

Comment: @ziganotschka resolved this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following goes back to 30 days from today for e.g. today's 25th Jan'22 so this will give you 25th Dec'21.

```
  "timeMin": {
              "function": "concat",
              "args": [
                {
                  "function": "date",
                  "args": [
                    "Y-m-d",
                    {
                      "function": "strtotime",
                      "args": [
                        "-30 days",
                        {
                          "function": "time"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "T00:00:00-04:00"
              ]
```